# How to derive the multivariate Pade Approximation for $\ln \left( {1 + \frac{x}{y}} \right)$?

Tags: approximation

How to derive the multivariate Pade Approximation for $\ln \left( {1 + \frac{x}{y}} \right)$ ?
In this case, multivariate mean variable $x$ and variable $y$.

Comment: What do you mean by it? Can you give a reference? The `PadeApproximant` command of Mathematica deals with one variable only.

Comment: How about `PadeApproximant[Log[1 + z], {z, 0, {2, 3}}] /. z -> x/y`

Comment: In case it helps your search, [Wiki reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant#Generalizations) that an approximant in two variables is called a Chisholm approximant, one in multiple variables a Canterbury approximant.

Comment: @MarcoB: There is no agorithm in the Chisholm's article. I'd like to quote "After the revised edition of this paper had been submitted, the author received a
copy of work by C. Lutterodt which also described two-variable approximants.
Lutterodt's choice of approximants is different from those studied in this paper; in
particular, they do not reduce to Padé approximants when one variable is equated to
zero".

Comment: @chris: Please, pay your attention to the above comment of me.

Comment: @user64494 The original paper by Chisholm mentions that the development of an algorithm still had to be done at that time. Since then, algorithms have been developed, e.g. a variation of the epsilon algorithm used for common Padé approximants ([Cuyt, Multivariate Padé approximants revisited, 1986](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01939363)). Cuyt herself also reviews the field's progress in [How well can the concept of Padé approximant be generalized to the multivariate case?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037704279900028X).

Comment: @MarcoB: Thank you for the references (only the latter is free), it's kind of you. I'd like to quote the latter: "In general, uniqueness of the general multivariate Pade approximant, in the sense that all rational functions in $[N/D]_E^f$ reduce to the same irreducible form, is not guaranteed, unless the index set $E\setminus N$ supplies a homogeneous system of linearly independent equations".

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh: You still don't formulate the definition of the bivariate Pade approximant.

Comment: so does it mean currently it is impossible to do so because of lack of rigour ?